# No Events for Dynamically Created Dropdowns in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm having an issue with events from dynamically created dropdowns in Bootstrap. When the dropdown is dynamically created, it will not trigger any events.

Here's a simple example to demonstrate, the original dropdown triggers the `alert()` without any issue but the dynamically appended dropdown does not.

http://jsfiddle.net/kynLqs1w/

HTML

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <a id="dropdown-original" href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Original Dropdown</a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>Dropdown content...</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="appendDropdown"></div>
<button id="createDropdown">Create Dynamic Dropdown</button>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#createDropdown").click(function() {
    $("#appendDropdown").html("<div class=\"dropdown\"><a id=\"dropdown-dynamic\" href=\"#\" class=\"dropdown-toggle\" data-toggle=\"dropdown\">Dynamic Dropdown</a><ul class=\"dropdown-menu\"><li>Dropdown content...</li></ul></div>");
  });

  $('.dropdown').on('show.bs.dropdown', function(e) {
    alert('show.bs.dropdown.event occurred!');
  });

});
```

Is there any way around this to use the events from the dynamic dropdown?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you register event before element created.

My solution is re-register when create new element. And don't forget to `off` event before register (it's cause created element trigger many time).

Check my [**working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/kynLqs1w/3/)

---

#### JS Code

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#createDropdown").click(function() {
    $("#appendDropdown").html("<div id=\"dropdown-dynamic\" class=\"dropdown\"><a id=\"dropdown-dynamic\" href=\"#\" class=\"dropdown-toggle\" data-toggle=\"dropdown\">Dynamic Dropdown</a><ul class=\"dropdown-menu\"><li>Dropdown content...</li></ul></div>");

    registerDropdownEvent();
  });
  registerDropdownEvent();
});

function registerDropdownEvent() {
  $('.dropdown').off('show.bs.dropdown');

  $('.dropdown').on('show.bs.dropdown', function(e) {
    alert('show.bs.dropdown.event occurred!');
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Create the event handler *after* the dropdown is created in the click event..

```
$("#createDropdown").click(function() {
    $("#appendDropdown").html("<div class=\"dropdown\"><a id=\"dropdown-dynamic\" href=\"#\" class=\"dropdown-toggle\" data-toggle=\"dropdown\">Dynamic Dropdown</a><ul class=\"dropdown-menu\"><li>Dropdown content...</li></ul></div>");
    $('.dropdown').on('show.bs.dropdown', function(e) {
         alert('show.bs.dropdown.event occurred!');
    });
});
```